# Redis does not use configuration file in minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, redis, configuration, minikube

I want to enable password for my Redis container in `minikube`. So, I enabled `requirepass` in `redis.conf`. Then, I generated the Docker image with this configuration file using the following `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM redis
COPY --chown=redis:redis redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
CMD ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
```

Then, I launch a pod with this image using the following `Deployment` YAML.

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: cache
  labels:
    run: cache
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: cache
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: cache
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: cache
          image: redis
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef: 
                name: redis-cfgmap
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "256Mi"
              cpu: "200m"
          imagePullPolicy: Never
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

Note, I am doing a `docker build -t redis:latest` from a shell that has run `eval $(minikube docker-env)`. Also, `imagePullPolicy` is set to `Never` so that the image is pulled from local Dokcer registry.

While the pod does come up, the logs mention that, the specified configuration file is not used.

```sh
6:C 27 Feb 2020 04:06:08.568 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
6:C 27 Feb 2020 04:06:08.568 # Redis version=5.0.7, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=6, just started
6:C 27 Feb 2020 04:06:08.568 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
6:M 27 Feb 2020 04:06:08.570 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
6:M 27 Feb 2020 04:06:08.570 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
6:M 27 Feb 2020 04:06:08.570 # Server initialized
6:M 27 Feb 2020 04:06:08.571 * Ready to accept connections
```

What is missing?

Comment: Run `docker system prune` on host (not vm), build it again and let me know if it helped

Comment: That worked. Thanks. It was using the image that was existing earlier due to `ImagePullPolicy: Never`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little more explanation for whom might want to read it.

It looks like for some reason the image you were building - instead of overwriting existing image as it should - wasn't doing it and you were stuck with `redis:latest` official image, not the one you just built.

When approaching this problem and trying to build the image I had the same issue as you and managed to solve it running `docker system prune`, but after that I didn't manage to replicate it one more time so its hard for me to say what was the real cause of it.

Anyway I am glad that it worked for you.